# Can not call embed css/js files

Tags: go

I'm embedding my css and js files as below:

```golang
package resources

import (
    "embed"
)

// WebUI is our static web ui from onsen ui.
//go:embed public/onsen
var WebUI embed.FS

// Views is our static web server layouts, views with dynamic content and partials content that is a static view.
//go:embed templates/layouts templates/views templates/partials
var Views embed.FS
```

And trying to define this `WebUI` as `static` folder in my main function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "onsen/resources"
)

var view *template.Template
var err error

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Starting up.")
    view = template.Must(template.ParseFS(resources.Views, "templates/layouts/*.html", "templates/views/*.html", "templates/partials/*.html"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading templates:" + err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(resources.WebUI))))
    //http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(resources.WebUI)))

    http.HandleFunc("/index", index)
    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:8070",
    }
    server.ListenAndServe()
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err = view.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

The folders structure is as shown:

[image]

But a running, I' getting the below errors:

[image]

```
CSS files: Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:8070/static/css/onsenui.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

JS files: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Typo? The stripped request path `css/onsenui.css` does not match the embed directive `//go:embed public/onsen`.  Did you intend to use a subdir of `resources.WebUI` in the call to create the static file server?

Comment: Yes @CeriseLimón, my intention is to use a subdir of `resources.WebUI` in the call to create the static file server.

Comment: Did you try that?  It should be something like  `http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.FS(fs.Sub(resources.WebU, "public/onsen"))))`.

Comment: That certainly explains the 404, and clearly none of those resources will be found at the invalid path ... but what's with the MIME type?

Comment: The 404 page returned from the CSS file has content type text/plain.  As an aside, I could not be of more help because the images are difficult for me to read.  Please post text in the form of text, not an image of the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by fixing the `static` route as:

```golang
http.Handle("/webUI/", http.StripPrefix("/webUI/", http.FileServer(http.FS(resources.WebUI))))
```

And both `css` and `js` files calls as:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webUI/public/onsen/css/onsenui.css"/>
```

that is:
`'The static path [/webUI] + the original route [public/onsen/...]`